# How to set up jboss eap 6 generate hprof file in AIX automatically when OOM occurs

Tags: jboss, out-of-memory, aix

How to set up `jboss eap 6 generate hprof` file in **IBM AIX 7.1** automatically when OOM occurs.

I have tried this parametter  `XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` in JVM configuration but still not generate. Thanks

Comment: Where you set it ? Have you deployed application or performed any operation which causes OOM ? Check bin dir of EAP default location of hprof file.

Comment: I have already set at domain.conf in bin dir. But just generate .phd format. I need .hprof format but not  successful